# Excesive amount of time to process with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

im having trouble to determine why is it taking up to 700 milliseconds to run the following

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_proyecto_all_sucess()
    {
        //Arrange
        var expectedItems = 4;

        var proyectoContext = new MultiLangDbContext(_dbOptions);
        var proyectoServ = new ProyectoService(proyectoContext);

        //Act
        var proyectoController = new ProyectoController(proyectoServ);
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var actionResult = await proyectoController.AllAsync();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine($"All: took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        var result = actionResult as ObjectResult;

        //Assert
        var returned = Assert.IsType<List<Proyecto>>(result.Value);
        returned.Count.Should().Be(expectedItems);
    }

    //here the function thats demanding that amount of time
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("All")]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> AllAsync()
    {
        var model = await _baseServ.GetTodosAsync();

        return Ok(model);
    }


    //here the service thats being called
    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetTodosAsync() => await _ctx.Set<T>().Where(x => !x._deleted).ToListAsync();

   //here the sql code being generated by entity
   SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Nombre], [p].[_deleted]
   FROM [Proyectos] AS [p]
   WHERE [p].[_deleted] <> CAST(1 AS bit)
```

and i have another similar test which is taking 40 milliseconds which is the following

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_proyecto_items_success()
    {
        //Arrange
        var pageSize = 3;
        var pageIndex = 0;

        var expectedItemsInPage = 3;
        var expectedTotalItems = 4;

        var proyectoContext = new MultiLangDbContext(_dbOptions);
        var proyectoServ = new ProyectoService(proyectoContext);

        //Act
        var proyectoController = new ProyectoController(proyectoServ);
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var actionResult = await proyectoController.PagedAsync(pageSize, pageIndex);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine($"Items: took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        var result = actionResult as ObjectResult;

        //Assert
        //Assert.IsType<PaginatedItemsViewModel<Proyecto>>(result.Value);
        result.Value.Should().BeOfType<PaginatedItemsViewModel<Proyecto>>();
        //var page = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<PaginatedItemsViewModel<Proyecto>>(result.Value);
        var page = result.Value.Should().BeAssignableTo<PaginatedItemsViewModel<Proyecto>>("Es el tipo de retorno").Which;
        page.Count.Should().Be(expectedTotalItems, "Por que es la cantidad de items no borrados");
        page.PageIndex.Should().Be(pageIndex, $"por que el indice pasado es {pageIndex}");
        page.PageSize.Should().Be(pageSize, $"por que el tamaño que le indicamos es de {pageSize}");
        page.Data.Count().Should().Be(expectedItemsInPage, $"por que el tamaño maximo es de {expectedTotalItems}");
    }

    //here the controller for this one
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("items")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(PaginatedItemsViewModel<Proyecto>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Proyecto>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> PagedAsync([FromQuery] int pageSize = 10, [FromQuery] int pageIndex = 0, string ids = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
        {
            var items = await _proyectoServ.GetByIdsAsync(ids);

            if (!items.Any())
            {
                return BadRequest("ids value invalid. Must be comma-separated list of numbers");
            }

            return Ok(items);
        }

        var totalItems = await _proyectoServ.GetTotal();

        var itemsOnPage = await _proyectoServ.GetPaged(pageSize, pageIndex, x => x.Nombre);

        var model = new PaginatedItemsViewModel<Proyecto>(pageIndex, pageSize, totalItems, itemsOnPage);

        return Ok(model);
    }
 
    //here the function being called    
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetPaged<TKey>(int pageSize = 10, int pageNumber = 0, System.Func<T, TKey> order = null)
    {
        //Si hay problemas con esto particularmente hay que ver si hay una mejor manera de implementar el orden y que sea compatible con Async
        if (order != null)
            return 
                _ctx.Set<T>()
                    .OrderBy(order)
                    .Where(x => !x._deleted)
                    .Skip(pageSize * pageNumber)
                    .Take(pageSize)
                    .ToList();
        else
            return await
                _ctx.Set<T>()
                    .Where(x => !x._deleted)
                    .Skip(pageSize * pageNumber)
                    .Take(pageSize)
                    .ToListAsync();
    }

 //here the sql being generated
 SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Nombre], [p].[_deleted]
 FROM [Proyectos] AS [p]
```

I tried numerous things up to now to see if i could make that 700 milliseconds (in memory sql ) / 1.1 seconds (in normal sql) and i couldnt, this is what i tried:

- My migrations had not set the max amount of characters so they were being generated with nvharchar(max)
  now Id is nvarchar(50), Nombre is nvharchar(60) and _deleted is bit. Nothing changed
- Before being a generic funtion it was being called like _ctx.Proyectos.Where(x => !x.deleted).ToListAsync(), this changed nothing also
- I tried with In Memory Sql and Normal SQL, the one that runs okay needs 40 ms/80 ms and the one thats not running okay is taking 700ms/1.1 seconds
- Both SQL were run in the Management studio, and the time it takes to process them is almost none
- I tried to run the test one by one to see if thats the problem, thats also a no

Honestly im out of options the only thing i can see working is making the sql call, but i would prefer for something as simple as this to be able to use the ORM. Any ideas?

Edit: This is the Mock for proyectos

```
    private IEnumerable<Proyecto> GetFakeProyectos()
    {
        return new List<Proyecto>() {
            new Proyecto() {
                Id = "0",
                Nombre = "Test1"
            },
            new Proyecto() {
                 Id = "1",
                Nombre = "Test2"
            },
            new Proyecto() {
                 Id = "2",
                Nombre = "Test3"
            },
            new Proyecto() {
                 Id = "3",
                Nombre = "Test4"
            },
            new Proyecto() {
                 Id = "5",
                Nombre = "Test5",
                _deleted = true
            },
        };
    }
```

Comment: How many records are there? Have you tried profiling your code to see where it spends its time?

Comment: Can you duplicate the test then run the test and the duplication?

Comment: @CodeCaster Only 5 records, i know its taking the time in the controller part, so provided thats only one line of code im thinking its inside entity framework part. I did it using a stop watch, any way to profile it further?

Comment: How do you measure the execution times you mentioned? Can you show the code if you use stopwatch?

Comment: @Vernou The duplicated test is taking 9 milliseconds

Comment: @VentsislavPetrov Im using the test explorer, and giving you the duration of the each test. I will edit my answer with both stop watches

Comment: Ahh, the first test always  requires a lot more time to run than the others.

Comment: So its a matter of it being the first test? , how can i make my test more accurate?

Comment: Unit tests aren't intended to do performance benchmarks. They are just not designed for that, with unit tests you are verifying the correctness of the unit. If you want to measure performance, it would be better to rely on proper benchmarking tools (like BenchmarkDotNet). You can setup some performance tests as well.

Comment: If you want post it as an answer and i ll make it as solved, thank you very much @VentsislavPetrov

Comment: To understand why the first call is slowest, see this on JIT work : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/managed-execution-process

Comment: + the first call in EF Core provoke a lot of initialization.

Comment: @Vernou, true, but he is creating a new DbContext in the Arrange phase of each test, so that's not the case here.

Comment: The model is generated one time and reused in each DbContext. The model is get [from a cache](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/69ce8af8c2b7ac90fc54798ea206d3770fb8db43/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/ModelSource.cs#L63) and the cache is [declared static](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/2ff3db33660c59e35d449dcbddd8d37dfba72b7b/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.cs#L95).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first unit test always requires a lot more time to run than the others, as it is loading some stuffs.

However, Unit Tests aren't good for performance measurements, they are just not designed for that purpose. With Unit Tests you are verifying the correctness of the code. If you want to measure its performance, better rely on proper benchmark tools (like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)). You can setup some performance tests as well.